# how do i see the url my computer is currently hitting?

Tags: macos, url, curl

I am on Mac OSX. I wrote a program to parse a few websites. The websites are being accessed using curl. How can I view which url my computer is currently hitting?

Answer (score 1):

If it's being called from your program, I'd add something to that program to print each website before running `curl`.  You can tell `curl` to print the URL it's fetched with something like this:

```
curl -w "%{url_effective}\n" -o "$outputfile" "$url"
```

... but that won't print the URL until *after* it finishes downloading it.  Also, note that this prints the effective URL to stdout; if the content of the web page is also going to stdout, they'll just get mixed together; you should only use this with `-o` or `-O` to redirect the web content.

Comment: Thank you for this but I need something I can view as the page hits are happening. I'm surprised there isn't a simple way to view outgoing network traffic from my computer.

Comment: You can view the network connections with `netstat -a | grep ESTABLISHED`, but it can't really tell you what website is being fetched, just the server's IP address.  For example, if I hit www.apple.com, I get directed to the server at 92.123.93.15; `netstat` can tell me that IP (with the `-n` flag), or try to reverse-translate that to a name (without `-n`) but that comes back to a92-123-93-15.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com.  The hostname and page curl are fetching are part of its private data; you'd have to use `tcpdump` or Wireshark to spy on that.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could try [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). Might be overkill, but then again if you're working with http it's a useful tool anyway.